# CSS help - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

On this site: https://capetownvegan.com

If you look at the home page, everything is perfect,
Then look at: https://capetownvegan.com/eateries-by-suburb/

You will notice the banner being streched, I add display: none to this.

```
.has-post-thumbnail .entry-thumbnail {
    display: none;
}
```

It works however it also affects the main page and the first row of blog images do not display., could anyone help figure this out?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: If you want specific css for a page, try looking for a unique class thats only used on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home page always has a class `home` on the body, and the other pages has the class `page` on the body. You can use this selector 
to specify the css.